# Summing up time taken in certain rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to know how much time a run of my program took in every row of code. I have a loop over around 300k objects with 1000 lines in the loop, and it takes its time.

Does VisualStudio have a possibility to highlight lines that took long during execution?

Comment: VS has tools such as a Profiler. It can tell you how much time is spent where.

Comment: See [beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If visual studio performance profiler is not enough. If other tools like JetBrains dotTrace are not available to you (BTW, 30-day trial version!). If sometimes you want to run your app and get real time counts in front of your face, your option is - run Microsoft SysInternals Debug Viewer application (free) and in your code, add to lines interesting to you. Lets say a line like this

```
var a = 6
```

Is not of any interest. But something else

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
. . . . . 
sw.Start();
// here is the line you want to time
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Line executed in " + sw.Elapsed);
```

Now, you will see this line in debug viewer. This is especially helpful if code is executed in IIS